# rails4-autocomplete. Getting association name in autocomplete field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add an auto complete field using https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete

I have a Topic model that belongs to a City. City belongs to Country. i.e. city = London. then city.country.name = England.

I can get my autocomplete to display the city name with

```
#controller
class TripsController < ApplicationController
    autocomplete :city, :name

#view
<%= f.autocomplete_field :city_id, autocomplete_city_name_trips_path %>
```

But I want the country name to show in the auto complete field too. i.e. London, England. not just London.

Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: also this passes the city name to the controller, I would like it to pass the city_id

Answer (score 1):

If you've got the country in another field then it is pretty easy with autocomplete. You want to use the update_elements option in your view to tell autocomplete what other fields need to be filled in.

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :city,
        autocomplete_department_name_incidents_path,
        update_elements: {country: '#trips_country'} %>
```

The `#trips_country` in the above snippet is the ID of the field in your form that you want updated. `country:` is extra data that autocomplete fetches for you.

So you also need to go to your form and tell autocomplete to grab other data.

```
autocomplete :city, :name, extra_data: [:country]
```

That's what would work if everything were in the same model. I've never tried to pull data from a different model using autocomplete so I don't know if it will work. Hopefully this is enough of a push to get you there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add a column to my cities model. How can I display the name in autocomplete, but send the id to the controller?

Comment: You want to send the ID to the controller so you can grab the right object from the database, right? One idea that comes to mind is to populate a hidden field with the ID. What I did in my most recent use of autocomplete was in my controller I used Model.find_or_create_by(field1: value_from_form, field2: value_from_form). In my case I wanted to create an object if it didn't exist, but find it if it did exist.

Comment: Before you add a column to your cities model, just try to get the country from the parent model. `autocomplete :city, :name, extra_data: [:country]`. I wouldn't go adding new columns unless you know that above chunk of code isn't going to work.

Comment: hi  Ihave the same issue,can u help me ?,, i have a brand model and car model , a brand has many cars,  i want to populate cars from a particular brand when i type brand..

Answer (score 0):

The rails4-autocomplete gem has the option [`display_value`](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete#display_value) which is what you want to use.

```
class TripsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :city, :name, display_value: :name_with_country
```

Then in the `City` model

```
def name_with_country
  name + ', ' + country.name
end
```